# Listing pending reboots in windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 x86 system, and I'm getting an error saying "Rule 'Restart computer' failed." I've already found a lot of people saying to clear the registry key 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations`, but sadly this key doesn't even exist in the registry on my server. I know I've run into this exact problem before, and that remedy did not work the previous time either. I eventually found a way to list the processes that currently require a reboot in Windows, which I used as a guide for what to uninstall. I cannot, for the life of me, find out how to do that again.

Does anyone know how to list the pending required reboots in windows via command line or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post (and powershell script):

http://www.techmumbojumblog.com/?p=375

But unfortunately I don't see a way to find out WHY a machine needs to reboot.

Comment: This link appears to have expired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the WhyReboot utility from here:
   http://exodusdev.com/products/whyreboot